# What is the workflow for developing Expo apps that use Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth, expo

I'm developing an iOS app that requires BLE but am confused as to the current state and workflow for getting Bluetooth into my app using Expo's tools.

So far I gather there are some constraints that I must work around:

- Simulator does not support Bluetooth
- Expo Go does not support Bluetooth

So (and I'm new to this so be patient) I gather that means I must either

- `expo run:ios -d` and run on a connected device, or
- `eas build -p ios` and download to devices.

But what's unclear (and I may not even have the above quite right, in fact I'd be happy to know that it's not that complex) is how to access Bluetooth in the first place. I see that the Expo API provides access to [all kinds of platform functionality](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/), but don't see Bluetooth anywhere there. I gather that in order to use Bluetooth, I must use `react-native-ble-plx` (ignoring the part where it says my project needs to be "ejected"?) for which [I need to add a corresponding plugin](https://expo.canny.io/feature-requests/p/bluetooth-1) with

```sh
yarn add @config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx expo-dev-client
```

and and the corresponding entry under `expo.plugins` in my `app.json`.

Do I have that right? Will those steps then give me access to platform Bluetooth (though not in Expo Go or Simulator)?

Answer (score 10):

See the [Getting Started](https://docs.expo.dev/development/getting-started/) guide for details on how to set up EAS build with `expo-dev-client`. Here is a summary:

```
# Create the project
npx create-expo-app my-app
cd my-app
expo install expo-dev-client

# Install EAS
npm install -g eas-cli

# Configure EAS (follow the instructions)
eas build:configure
```

Then see the [@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx](https://github.com/expo/config-plugins/tree/main/packages/react-native-ble-plx) for instructions to install the plugin:

```
expo install react-native-ble-plx @config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx
```

Add the following entry to your `app.json`:

```json
{
  "expo": {
    "plugins": ["@config-plugins/react-native-ble-plx"]
  }
}
```

You can build the development version of your app with the following command (this will include the `react-native-ble-plx` plugin you added earlier in the build):

```
eas build --profile development --platform ios
```

Finally you can start the dev client to work on your app:

```
npx expo start --dev-client
```

Comment: Typo: should be `npx expo install expo-dev-client`

Comment: I think I installed expo with `npm -g install expo` and then you can directly use `expo` from your command line.